# Expectation and convergence of sum of RVs

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, weak-convergence

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of independent random variables and their distribution be $P_{X_n} = \text{N}(a,\sqrt{n})$.

Consider

$$
  Y_n = \frac{2}{n^2+n} \sum_{k=1}^n k X_k
$$

$(a) \;$ Show $E[Y_n] = a$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and

$(b) \;$ $Y_n \xrightarrow{P} a$.

---

First notice the $X_n$ are independent but *not* identically distributed. Notice I can't use the MGF of the normal distribution because this hasn't been dealt with in my course yet.

Applying linearity of expectation we get

$$
\begin{align*}
  E[Y_n] &= E\left[ \frac{2}{n^2+n} \sum_{k=1}^n k X_k \right] \\
  &= \frac{2}{n^2+n} E\left[\sum_{k=1}^n k X_k \right] \\
  &= \frac{2}{n^2+n} \sum_{k=1}^n \Big( k E[X_k] \Big)
\end{align*}
$$

where $E[X_k] = a$ by the normal distribution.

So we get

$$
  E[Y_n] = \frac{2}{n^2+n} \sum_{k=1}^n ka = \frac{2a}{n(n+1)} \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = a
$$

So far things are good. Now for the second part. I've read to my manuscript numerous times and I'm sure I have to use this Lemma here:

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables with $E[X_n^2] < \infty$ for all $n$. If $E[X_n] \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} a$ and $\text{Var}(X_n) \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$, then $X_n \overset{P} \longrightarrow a$.

Replacing $X_n$ with $Y_n$ from part $(a)$ we know that $E[Y_n] = a \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} a$. Now one could show that the variance goes to zero (I'm not entirely sure here if this is true, haven't completed this exercise yet). However my question is, could we apply the definition of convergence in probability here and use some inequality like Chebyshev's to prove this same result?

Comment: The variance of $X_n$ is $1/\sqrt{n}$ agree? Then it is clear that this converges to zero as n converges to infinity.

Comment: $\operatorname{Var}(Y_n)=\frac{4}{(n^2+n)^2}\sum_{k=1}^n k^{5/2}\le \frac{4}{(n^2+n)^2}n\cdot n^{5/2}\to 0$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you!